# Nature of the series $\sum 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series $\sum 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)$ .is 
1. Convergent 
2. Oscillates finitely
3. Divergent
4. Oscillates infinitely

I found first few terms of this series, which are 4-4+8-8+...
So it seems like I will get such pairs if I expand the series more. But what can we conclude about the nature of the series at infinity? The series is oscillating infinitely. So can I say it is divergent?

Comment: You can easily rule out $(1)$ and $(3)$. Now look at the positive terms to find the final answer.

Comment: @Peter, do you mean (1) and (2) rather than (1) and (3)?

Comment: @BarryCipra I mean $(3)$ Divergent means that the partial sums exceed every positive (or in absolute terms every negative) value from some point on. Here we have the partial sums $4,0,8,0,12,0,16,0,\cdots$, so the series does not diverge.

Comment: @Peter, I grew up with the definition that divergent simply means not convergent.

Comment: In German we have "bestimmt divergent" (I do not know the english translation) which is distinguished from "oscillating". If we take sequences, $-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,\cdots$ is for example oscillating , whereas $1,2,3,4,\cdots$ is divergent. Given the options in the question, it must be meant in such a way, otherwise the "oscillating"-options would not make sense. A difficult case is $-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,\cdots$, but I would not consider this as divergent either, but oscillating.

Comment: @Peter, it sounds like the modifier *bestimmt* (which translates as "certainly") is important here. In English, we would say something like "diverges to infinity" (or even "*converges* to infinity," if you get fancy by compactifying the reals with an extra point or two). Maybe the key thing here is for the OP to stipulate *their* understanding of what it means to be divergent.

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n=1+(-1)^{n+1}(2n+1)$, the $(a_n)$ is unbounded, hence $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0$. Thus $\sum a_n $ is divergent.

Comment: I am a little confused! Definition of a divergent series says that a series is divergent if it is not convergent. I read somewhere, bieng divergent and bieng infitely oscillatory are different. A series is said to be divergent if it diverges to infinite or -infinite.

Answer (score 1):

For a series to converge the general term must tend to $0$. In this case it doesn't so the series is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Surely oscillates infinitely since $$a_{n}=2n+2\quad,\quad n\text{ is odd}\\a_{n}=-2n\quad,\quad n\text{ is even}$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for contradiction that  the series $\sum 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)$ converges, then the sequence $$1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)\to 0,\;\;\text{ as }n\to\infty.$$
However, \begin{align} c_n:= 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)=\begin{cases}2n+2,&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is even,}\\-2n,&\text{if}\;n\;\text{is odd.}\end{cases}  \end{align}

\begin{align}\text{Thus, for odd} \; n\in\Bbb{N},\; c_n= -2n\to -\infty,\;\text{while}\; c_n= 2n+2\to \infty\;\text{for even} \;n,\text{contradiction.}\end{align}
Therefore, option $(1)$ is eliminated. Now, by Direct Comparison
\begin{align}\infty= \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (2n+2)\leq \infty\;\text{and} \;-\infty\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-2n)\leq\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} -n= -\infty\end{align}
Option $(3)$ is eliminated because 
\begin{align}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)=\infty\; \text{if}\;n\;\text{is even}\end{align}
\begin{align}\text{and}\;\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} 1+(-1)^{n+1} (2n+1)=-\infty\; \text{if}\;n\;\text{is odd.}\end{align}
Hence, it [oscillates infinitely](http://www.mathematicsdictionary.com/english/vmd/full/o/oscillatingseries.htm).